# need from 7 to 8 hours to sleep or need to sleep from 7 to 8 hours

Tags: word-order

Quesion: ''How many  hours of sleep do we need to sleep a night?''

Possible  answers:

1. We need from 7 to 8 hours to sleep a night.
2. We need to sleep from 7 to 8 hours a night.

Which is better? I prefer 2 as I think ''need  to sleep'' is a verb phrase.

Are both grammatical?

Comment: Number 2 is definitely better. Alternatively, you could say: "We need 7 to 8 hours' sleep a night".

Comment: What @Ronald Sole said. There's also *We need to sleep 7 to 8 hours a night*, and to be honest I think both those alternatives are more likely than either of OP's versions. But it's really a matter of personal opinion and preferred style rather than "grammar" as such.

Comment: Neither is idiomatic. "We need between 7 and 8 hours of sleep a night". "We need to sleep for between 7 and 8 hours per night".

Comment: This is not an opinion-based question. #1 is ungrammatical.  You close-voters need more sleep.

Comment: @JavaLatte: #2 is  idiomatic in AmE.  **from** is optional.

Answer (score 5):

a) We need ... something.

b) We need ... to do something.

We need *sleep* (it).

We need *to sleep*  (to do it).

How much of it do we need?

We need 7 to 8 hours (of) *sleep* each night.

How much, or for how long, do we need to do it?

We need to sleep 7 to 8 hours each night.